# Ajax popup activated by pressing the form field

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, popup, field

Basically I just want to create a popup (forget the content of the popup, and forget the styling), that is activated like the signup form is on: 
http://www.babycenter.com/

Basically I want a small form field, and when I press that form field, the ajax popup should occur.

I want to create it both on my asp powered webshop, and my php powered blog.

How would you do this? :/

Thnx
/Helio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on text field you can use 2 different events handlers: click and focus.
so, let say the field has an id "field" - in that case, you can use either:
$('#field').click(showPopUp()) or $('#field').focus(showPopUp()), 
when showPopUp is the function that shows the popup (with .show, .fadeIn or whatever, and if using $.ajax or something else).